# Required<Partial<Inner>> doesn't extends Inner

Tags: typescript

I have a code similar to the following one:

```js
type Inner = {
  a: string
}
type Foo<I extends Inner> = { f: I }
interface Bar<I extends Inner> {
  b: I
}
type O<I extends Partial<Inner>> = Foo<Required<I>> & Bar<Required<I>
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdnCAnKBeKBvAUFXUCGAXFAM7BICWcA5lgL5aiRQBiA9mwDwxQQAewCHAAmJWAmQA+NJigAzYjwZVBSOfgDG0AEL4k3XgKGjxiJNOx4oAI0X1G4aAHkD-QSLEAFPcAr4ANtwS5tLo7FwAShAAjgCuFEgQwtyS0gBkULr6UXEJSSlAA)

But the code above doesn't compile with the following error:

```
Type 'Required<I>' does not satisfy the constraint 'Inner'.
  Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'I["a"]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
      Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2344)
```

I'm expecting that `Required<Partial<Inner>>` extends `Inner`.

Comment: You're missing a `>` on your last `type = ` line (it's not the problem, though).

Comment: `Required<Partial<Inner>>` isn't what you have, though. You have `Required<I>` where `I extends Partial<Inner>`.  For normal compiler options, a required property including `undefined` in its domain extends an optional property.  So `{a: "abc" | undefined}` extends `Partial<Inner>` but not `Inner`, and `Required<{a: "abc" | undefined}>` extends `Partial<Inner>` but not `Inner`.  See [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKvXZm) for an example.  Does that fully address your question?  If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing

Comment: @jcalz - Heh, I was writing up something very similar as you commented. Just curious: What compiler options would change the behavior? You seemed to have something in mind in your comment above. (It's probably obvious to you, but I'm not as up-to-speed on all the compiler options as I should be.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If you turn on `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` then the compiler will disallow assigning `{a: undefined}` to `{a?: string}` and then the hole this code falls into isn't there.  The compiler will *still* complain, though, because its analysis of lookup types still thinks `undefined` is possible.  But I don't know if it's worth exploring too much in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `I extends Partial<Inner>` means that `I` can be a *subtype* of `Partial<Inner>`, and there are subtypes of `Partial<Inner>` that — even passed through `Required` — aren't type-compatible with the `I extends Inner` constraint on `Foo`. Here's an example of one such type:

```typescript
type Incompatible = Partial<Inner> & {a: undefined};
```

That's a valid subtype of `Partial<Inner>`, because the definition of `Partial<Inner>` is `{a?: string | undefined}`. But `Required<Incompatible>` doesn't turn it back into something that extends `Inner`, it just turns it into `{a: undefined}`. If you try to use that with `Foo` like this, it fails for the same reason your mapped type fails:

```typescript
type Q = Foo<Required<Incompatible>>;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdnCAnKBeKBvAUFXUCGAXFAM7BICWcA5lgL4DcWokUAYgPYcA8MUEAD2AQ4AExKwEyAHxpMUAGbE+dLFWFIF+AMbQAQviS9+QkeMmIks7HigAjZfWbho8bRwC2YfMAp2ANtDoAAqGvvj+vFJWUABkmERQAK5iEApUEKKMWAD0OXgAegD8zqwAShAAjkkUSJkAgtT4VHIV1bWZUe5ePn6B0kx5hSUs0ACKcpw8bTV1ol2e3r4BENIDQA)

How you fix it — if you can, in a type-safe way — will be very specific to your real situation. For instance, it's tempting to do:

```typescript
type RequiredInner<T extends Partial<Inner>> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends undefined ? Key extends keyof Inner ? Inner[Key] : never : T[Key];
};
```

...and then use `Foo<RequiredInner<I>>`. And although [that works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdnCAnKBeKBvAUFXUCGAXFAM7BICWcA5lgL4DcWokUAYgPYcA8MUEAD2AQ4AExKwEyAHxpMUAGbE+dLFWFIF+AMbQAQviS9+QkeMmIks7HigAjZfWbho8bRwC2YfMAp2ANtDoAAqGvvj+vFJWUABkmERQAK5iEApUEKKMWAD0OXgAegD8zqwAShAAjkkUSJkAgtT4VHIV1bWZUe5ePn6B0kx5hSUs0ACKcpw8bTV1ol2e3r4BENIDWKXQMx2i8JbcAComwmISoUjhkXsysug2eADaANIQIFAtANavHApQBwC6xAOz1e-2OZgkKVEaQyoigRSgLzeghO5i+IB+FmQ8KxSBBIDBxEQADdsUD8f8mNlRlAxgAmSZcbjbObXIxuRa9FZrJhAA), it makes a **major** assumption which **may not be sound**: That you don't have a runtime value of `{a: undefined}` where you have that `Partial<Inner>`. That assumption isn't typesafe. (But [jcalz points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76323601/requiredpartialinner-doesnt-extends-inner?noredirect=1#comment134589984_76323601) in a comment on the question that using the [`exactOptionalPropertyTypes`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exactOptionalPropertyTypes) option could prevent that assignment, though that flag doesn't solve your problem.) So I don't think we can give you a general way to solve it in your real code. But hopefully understanding the problem will help you solve it.